# Prevent List changes in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linked-list, readonly

I have a Linkedlist of objects (can be changed to any other Collection type as long as it keeps entry order) in assembly A (DLL).

When Assembly B creates an object from the class that contains said LinkedList, it assigns a method to report back some information. One of the arguments that the method takes is said LinkedList.

Now i want this method in Assembly B to be able to read from that LinkedList (traverse it and do stuff based on it's content), however i need to prevent that method from changing the data in the List.

While i am the one using Assembly A right now, When and if it goes public, I need to prevent the data from being changed from outside my assembly so that no 3rd party using the library can fidget with results within the assembly.

Basicly i am looking to 'seal' the parameter that brings that LinkedList from Assembly A to Assembly B

Am I making any sense?

Comment: Two aspects here, changing the list and changing the elements in the list.  The latter requires property setters with *internal* accessibility.

Comment: @HansPassant: Good catch. Of course i meant change contents

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
new List<T>(linkedList).AsReadOnly();
```

Comment: This might well be the best answer - I was hoping not to need to get it into a list - so it wouldn't need to have it all in contiguous memory, but i can live with that

Answer (score 5):

If you can change from `LinkedList<T>` to `List<T>`, you could use the [`AsReadOnly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx) method to produce a read-only wrapper of your list. The wrapper is lightweight, does not require copying, and immediately reflects the changes to the underlying collection:

```
List<MyClass> originalList = ...
IList<MyClass> readOnly = originalList.AsReadOnly();
```

Comment: abatishchev said it first - sorry - good explanation though +1

Comment: Nice, the extra info about IList was useful to make my interface support both taking a "temporary" list (that will survive thx to keeping reference to it) and a persistent list you'll want to pass AsReadOnly from the caller side (although this is not enforced, so caller must be careful).

Comment: I'd rather use `IReadOnlyList<T>` to get compile time errors in case you try to accidetially modify your list.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing the *real* linked list to B's callback method, pass a copy. That way, B can do whatever it wants with the list without being able to modify the original list.

Creating a copy of a linked list is easy using the [LinkedList(IEnumerable) constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sb8tw8x.aspx):

```
var copy = new LinkedList<MyType>(originalList);
```

Clearly, the *elements* of the list can be modified by B, if they are mutable, but I am sure that you are aware of that.

Comment: This is one thing i thought of - however, has the LinkedList may contain anything derived from object, this will only do a shallow copy. Probably won't allow Add/Remove (test needed to be sure) but would allow change values inside the objects - or am i wrong?

Comment: I will create a copy with the same objects but new `LinkedListNode`s. Thus, it *will* allow Add and Remove, but that won't matter, since this will only affect B's copy of the LinkedList. Of course, modifying the objects themselves *will* affect A, but this is the same for all the other solutions proposed here.

Comment: not really - the accepted answer makes it read only - trying to change it will throw an exception at runtime

Comment: @537mfb: Trying to change *the list* (i.e. adding or removing) will throw an exception. Modifying the objects themselves is still possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think that returning `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>` should fix your problem. The easiest way:

```
foreach( var t in list )
    yield t;
```

This way you'll return enumerator only. Consumer will not be able to change the content of the list.

Comment: Notice that it will iterate the list each time consumer access this code.

Comment: @abatishchev there is nothing stopping developer to do it once, cache it, and iterate over only if elements were added, removed... This snippet was provided only to illustrate the idea.

Comment: Contents of list should change once before each report back call so this would become too cumbersom for my particular case - good anwer though

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some code.

It sounds like you want to allow them to work with a copy of the data. That way if they do change it in some way, the original copy remains unmodified.

Look at the `ICloneable` interface for duplicating an object and create a completely new linked list, with copies of all the original contents and pass that back to Assembly B.

Comment: That is definitly a possible solution - would have to be a deep copy though - with the problem arrising from not beeing able to be sure that the objects in the LinkedList are IClonable and not even knowing upfront what their type is, beeing even possible they are from 3rd party custom classes